# angularjs $resource how to call multiple services

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, angularjs-service

I've just started with angularjs yesterday and have reached [this part of the tutorial](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.18/docs/tutorial/step_11) where there is an example of using $resource  for accessing data from services. I am running this example in ASP.Net MVC and have a slightly different configuration of where the json files are stored. The json file containing the list of phones and the bunch of files containing the detailed description of each phone are in separate folders. 
Now the problem as I see it, is this line:

```
return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
```

As per my folder structure the json file containing the list of phones is accessible using this line which I modified from the one above

```
  return $resource('/MyAngularScripts/:phoneId.json.htm', {}, {
      query: { method: 'GET', params: { phoneId: 'jsonPhonedata' }, isArray: true }
```

I changed the extension to .htm because I did not want to add another handler to IIS express. That file extension is not the problem as I can see the list of phones. Now when I click on each phone I should be able to see its detail description from the json file which is another folder. 
The folder is: `/Content/PhoneData/{all the various phone data json files here}`

Currently I get a 404 not found because the detail file is in `/Content/PhoneData/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.json.htm`  but I am hitting the url as `/MyAngularScripts/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.json.htm`

How do I modify my Service as it is now to allow two different URLS?

Current Service code:

```
var phonecatServices = angular.module('phonecatServices', ['ngResource']);

phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
      return $resource('/MyAngularScripts/:phoneId.json.htm', {}, {
          query: { method: 'GET', params: { phoneId: 'jsonPhonedata' }, isArray: true }
      });
  }]);
```

Current controller code for getting list of phones:  `$scope.phones = Phone.query();`

Current controller code for getting detail of selected phone:

```
 $scope.phone = Phone.get({ phoneId: $routeParams.phoneId }, function (phone) {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = phone.images[0];
  });
```

How do I modify the controller code to call the services as well?

Comment: Which is the actual url `#1 /MyAngularScripts/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.json.htm` or `#2 /Content/PhoneData/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.json.htm`

Comment: the list of phones is in /MyAngularScripts/jsonPhonedata.json.htm and the selected phones detail is in /Content/PhoneData/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.json.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify url for each action

```
 return $resource(
           "/MyAngularScripts/:phoneId.json.htm",
           { Id: "@Id" },
           {
               'get':{url:'/Content/PhoneData/'+:phoneId+'json.html},
               'query' : {url:'/MyAngularScripts/jsonPhonedata.json.html'},

           }
      );
```